# Sum of all numbers entered in a listview's edittext

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I have a listview in my activity with a textview and an edittext of inputType number, the user will enter numbers in each edit text.There is a textview which displays the sum of all the numbers entered. How do i calculate the sum and show it in the textview as soon as the user enters the amount.
I tried it this way :

```
holder.tvDonationAmount.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        try {
            amount = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvDonationAmount.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        addn_array.add(amount);

        for (int j = 0; j < addn_array.size(); j++) {
            try {
                sum += addn_array.get(j);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried adding each element after he's entered the number into an Arraylist of Integers and add the elements which throws the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at the line inside for loop sum+ = . .
```

I also implemented this in my Textwatcher like this

```
private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {



    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        try {

            amount = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvDonationAmount.getText().toString());
            addn_array.add(amount);

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        Toast.makeText(context, ""+addn_array.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for (int j = 0; j <addn_array.size(); j++) {

            try {
                sum += addn_array.get(j);

                Toast.makeText(context, ""+sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        Toast.makeText(context, "" + sum, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};`
```

It throws this error.

```
[![Logcat][1]][1]
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this or can you please suggest any better way if there's any?

Comment: What happens when you run your app? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: I get this error ' java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
                                                                             at com.quatriz.donateazy.Adapters.FinalDTAdapter$1.onFocusChange' At the line sum+ = ....

Comment: Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: `addn_array.get(j)` returns `null`. I suggest that you use the debugger to inspect the elements of your `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at TextWatchers. You don't need a focus change listener, but a TextWatcher, since it listens to changes you make to the text inside the EditText.
Here is a great example: http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-textwatcher-example

Comment: Tried the same with text watcher throws the same error as mentioned in the question at the same line of code.

Comment: Can you please provide the code with the TextWatcher?

Comment: I have added the textwatcher code in the question and the image of my logcat , please have a look.

Comment: Is this the only error you get?

    [![Logcat][1]][1]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in case a `NumberFormatException` is thrown when parsing `amount`, `amount` can be `null`. Thus, `null` is added to the list.

```
try {
    amount = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvDonationAmount.getText().toString());
    addn_array.add(amount);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will solve your `NullPointerException`.
Please do use a `TextWatcher` like @Gregorio Palamà suggested.

Comment: I made your suggested changes.  I have added the textwatcher code in the question and the image of my logcat , please have a look.